# Pass an inner function of a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, parameters

I have a class like this

```
class A:
    def a(self, params):
       ...
    def b(self, params):
       ...
    def c(self, function, *params):
       function(params)
    def d(self):
       ...
       self.c(self.a, params)
       self.c(self.b, params)
```

... but it gives me an error on executing `d`.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `class A {` isn't valid Python?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `params` in `d`?

Comment: `params` is not defined in `d` method's scope.

Comment: please, make sure you code works and post the error. what you shared is not valid python  class.

Comment: Please provide a real [mcve]. You've left too much out.

Comment: _gives me an error_ is not information we can use to help. What is the error? Have you included the line where the error is thrown?

Comment: I do not know what `a` and `b` do, however consider replacing `c` with `function(*params)` (I've added the * before params) to avoid problem in `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

you should call `c` instance method method using `self.c(...`

Comment: I am doing this i have corrected